# How to create layered pandas data frame using Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to create a data frame as below.

```
C1  C2  C3  C4

1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
1   2   2   3
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   5
2   3   4   6
3   4   5   7
```

The C4 column should be unique values. C4 column values should belongs to any one of the C3 column. C3 column values should belongs to any one of the C2 column. C2 column values should belongs to any one of the C1 column. The column values should be C1 < C2 < C3 < C4. The values may be random.

I used below sample Python code.

```
import  pandas as pd
import  numpy as np

C1 =  [1, 2]
C2 =  [1, 2, 3,4]
C3 =  [1, 2, 3, 4,5]
C4 =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Z = [C1,C2,C3,C4]

n = max(len(x) for x in Z)
a = [np.hstack((np.random.choice(x, n - len(x)), x)) for x in Z]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=['C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4']).T.sample(frac=1)
print (df)
```

Below is my output.

```
 C1 C2 C3 C4
  1  4  2  2
  1  3  4  6
  2  1  2  4
  1  2  5  1
  2  4  5  7
  1  2  3  5
  2  2  1  3
```

But I couldn’t get the output as per my logic. The value 2 in C3 column belongs to 1 and 4 of C2 column. Also the value 2 in C2 column belongs to 1 and 2 of C1 column. Guide me to get output as per my logic. Thanks.

Comment: So, imagine if the output of your code is sorted, per column would this solve your problem???

Comment: @ Anwarvic: C4 column has unique values. So, even it get sorted the problem not solved.

Comment: But C4 still has unique values.

Comment: @Anwarvic: Thank for your response. C4 should be unique always. That is my expectation.

Comment: This [image](https://ibb.co/RyC4Mw9) is what I meant by sorting the output of your code. Is this what you are looking for? If no, then what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Anwarvic After sorting the row sequences are changed. I need same row sequence before and after. As per my opinion this kind of sorting will not solve my logic as per in my question. Thanks.